# Which (tcp/udp) ports are best suited to be implemented at the server side of a mobile application?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, port, serversocket

Since ISPs as well as company networks (eg. when connected via WiFi) tend to block different ports, is there a best practise of choosing a specific portnumber when developing the server part of a mobile app?

I am talking about the choice of a listening port on the sever, that the app connects to (either udp or tcp), with a non-REST/non-HTTP(S) response.

#### What I found so far

- Different people on the net mentioned that using a high port number (like 50k upwards) would be appropriate, since those are not assigned (which makes most sense to me, except they might be altogether blocked)
- So others suggest using port 80 or 443, since they rarely get blocked by anyone
- Again others suggested using ports like 81 or 8080 (but this seems like the worst of both worlds since 8080 is on the one hand usually used for proxying, on the other hand often blocked for the same reason)

As for me, I am about to implement a simple websockets server on something other than port 80 (if at all feasible), but I am actually even more interested in what to generally pick as a best practice (also UDP).

Thank you all!

Comment: If it's an HTTP server use port 80. If it's HTTPS use 443. It doesn't appear to be anything other than those two so it isn't clear why you're even asking.

Comment: @EJP: For websockets this is common, but first of all in my case there is already a webserver running (with these ports) so my ws server has to use something different, secondly I am thinking of doing udp connections in the future (which would be necessary for a decent 3D app/game) and this sure should have different ports. Just the question if it is best to take something like 51638 and cross my fingers that it is not blocked? I don't know, that is why I am asking! :-/ But thx for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Use 80 or 443 not others. For an app I used 8080 but some ISPs blocked that port. To check that I have to add a checking connection when the app starts, if there is no connection a message is sent to a service in port 80, that is why I noticed that it is not good using other ports than 80 or 443.